# Javascript Slider into PHP Variable

Tags: php, javascript

The javascript below creates a slider within a form that has the submission code on the same page.

The code within the form that shows the slider from the javascript is

`<div id="outbox-bottom">Callback time selected <span style="font-size:9px">(Ex Weekends):</span> <span id="callback_selected"></span></div>`

I need a way to get the time that was selected on the slider into a variable that I can use to get in my form as in `$time = $_POST['time'];`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#callback_selected').html("9 am");
  var select = jQuery( "#callback" );
  var slider = jQuery( "<div id='slider'></div>" ).insertAfter( select ).slider({
    min: 1,
    max: 12,
    range: "min",
    value: 1,
    step: .5,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
        $time_int = ui.value;
        if (ui.value < 5) {
            $time_int = $time_int + 8;
            if ($time_int.toString().substr(-2) == '.5') $time_int = $time_int.toString().split('.')[0] + ":30";
            $time_selected = $time_int + " am";
        } else {
            $time_int = $time_int - 4;
            if ($time_int.toString().substr(-2) == '.5') $time_int = $time_int.toString().split('.')[0] + ":30";
            $time_selected = $time_int + " pm";
        }
      jQuery('#callback_selected').html($time_selected);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a hidden input into your form:

`<input type="hidden" name="time" id="time" value="" />`

Then, once they've selected the time and you're updating the html `#callback_selected`, add another to update the value of the hidden field.  It will post the value along with the form.

```
// Rest of your script...
jQuery("#time").val($time_selected);
```

Now you should be able to find the `time` value in your post.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're going to need to use some Ajax to send that data to PHP.

Check this out:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Basically you'll have an Ajax functions that sends arguments to a php file. From there you can do what you need with the variables you send.